# How to build/run container with writable file system using Singularity 3?

Tags: docker, rstudio-server, singularity-container

I am using Singularity 3.0 and trying to pull a container image from DockerHub and run it on a university cluster.  I followed [this recipe](https://www.rocker-project.org/use/singularity/) to get started.

```
singularity pull --name rstudio-3.5.2.sif docker://rocker/rstudio:3.5.2
singularity exec --bind example-project-1/:/home/rstudio/ rstudio-3.5.2.sif rserver --www-port 8787
```

The container process starts but when I try to connect via a browser I get the following error log.

```
01 Jan 2019 12:07:22 [rsession-pughdr] ERROR system error 30 (Read-only file system) [path=/home/pughdr/.rstudio, target-dir=]; OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::FilePath::createDirectory(const string&) const /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/core/FilePath.cpp:846; LOGGED FROM: rstudio::core::FilePath rstudio::core::system::userSettingsPath(const rstudio::core::FilePath&, const string&) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/core/system/PosixSystem.cpp:486
01 Jan 2019 12:07:22 [rsession-pughdr] ERROR system error 30 (Read-only file system) [path=/home/pughdr/.rstudio, target-dir=]; OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::FilePath::createDirectory(const string&) const /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/core/FilePath.cpp:846; LOGGED FROM: int main(int, char* const*) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:1689
```

Seems that the file system in the container is only read-only. How do I build (or run) the container such that the container's file system is writable?

**Update:**

I was able to get the RStudio Server running on the university cluster as follows.

```
singularity exec --home my-project-directory rstudio-3.5.2.sif rserver --www-port 8787
```

This seems to work because Singularity automatically mounts the user's home directory on the host into the container and I redefined my home directory to be `my-project-directory` in the above.

However I still cannot install R packages into the container as the file system is not writable.

```
> install.packages(c("plyr", "dply", "tidyr", "ggplot2"))
Installing packages into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
Would you like to use a personal library instead? (yes/No/cancel) cancel
Error in install.packages : unable to install packages
```

Original question still stands: how can I create a Singularity 3.* container that has a writable filesystem? If this is not possible, explanation as to why would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Reading in this [article](https://divingintogeneticsandgenomics.rbind.io/post/run-rstudio-server-with-singularity-on-hpc/), apparently there is a solution to the problem concerning package installation:

Create an `.Renviron` file in your home directory and set `R_LIBS_USER` as follows:

```
# User-installed R packages go into their home directory
echo 'R_LIBS_USER=~/R/%p-library/%v' >> ${HOME}/.Renviron
```

This solved the package-installation-issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

try --writable flag in your container:

```
singularity build --writable rstudio-3.5.2.sif docker://rocker/rstudio:3.5.2

singularity exec --writable --bind example-project-1/:/home/rstudio/ rstudio-3.5.2.sif rserver --www-port 8787
```

Comment: The `--writable` flag was deprecated in Singularity 3.0 and requires `sudo` rights (which I don't have on university cluster) for Singularity 2.5.

Comment: The `--writable-tmpfs` replicates the docker behaviour:  "makes the file system accessible as read-write with non persistent data (with overlay support only)"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sandbox folder with --sandbox option .

Also you probably can create a Virtual Machine / vagrant for singularity 2.5